# mySQL Query design - calculating a vote score for multiple content items

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a content items table structured like

```
|  contentid |   message     |    categoryid  |  userid  |    dateadded | etc.. 
     15          foo bar            3             4           somedate
     16          more foo bar       3             4           somedate
     16          foo stuff          3             4           somedate
```

and a votes table, where direction = 1 = an up vote, and = 2 being a down vote.

```
|  voteid   |  contentid |  userid  |  direction |    dateadded
    7             15          4            1           some date
    8             15          6            1           some date
    9             15          17           2           some date
```

And I'd like to select a set of content items, having an additional column on the end with its calculated score based on the votes in the votes table.

Previously, I had a 'score' column attached to the content table, and each time a vote was cast, it would update its score. This was done so I wouldnt have to have a more complex query to calculate scores on each SELECT, but I'd like to change this now.

This votes table was designed a while ago, so if changing all the votes values to something other than 1 or 2 (perhaps -1 for a downvote) would make it easier, I will update the entire table.

What would the query be to pull all content items, each with a score in a calculated column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the vote "direction" represents up and down votes:

```
SELECT i.contentid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.direction = 1 THEN 1
                WHEN v.direction = 2 THEN -1
                ELSE 0 END) AS Votes
    FROM items i
        LEFT JOIN votes v
            ON i.contentid = v.contentid
    GROUP BY i.contentid
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN v.direction = 1 THEN 1
                WHEN v.direction = 2 THEN -1
                ELSE 0 END) > -3
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. If I use this new 'Votes' calculated column in a WHERE clause, it complains that it doesnt know what 'Votes' is (e.g. to select content greater than -3 lets say). How can I reference a calculated column after declaring it here?

Comment: @Barfoon: You'd test that with a `HAVING` clause. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks. In this case you have to perform the `SUM` twice?

Comment: Yes. You cannot reference the column alias `Votes` in the having clause.

Comment: +1 @barfoon: I'd guess that mysql is smart enough to *perform* the `SUM` only once, anyway. Also note that you could eliminate the `CASE` if you altered your vote direction column to use the natural -1 for a downvote.

Comment: Thanks all - I've posted a linked question if you are up for taking a shot at a more complex query that would improve what I had.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  items.*,
  SUM(direction = 1) - SUM(direction = 2) AS score
FROM items
LEFT JOIN votes USING (contentid)
GROUP BY contentid
```

The reason this works is because a true comparison evaluates to `1` and a false one to `0`.